# When job is printed, last job status is JOB_STATUS_RETAINED, instead of JOB_STATUS_PRINTED

Tags: c++, winapi, print-spooler-api

I poll printer queue on any change like JOB_CHANGE, and if I see that some job disappeared, I report to server that job has been printed or deleted, according to job last status.

Problem is that printer Lexmark X945e returned last job status only JOB_STATUS_RETAINED, but no JOB_STATUS_DELETED or JOB_STATUS_PRINTED.

What does that mean? Can I use retained status to say that job was printed?

Comment: Do you mean JOB_STATUS_RETAINED when you say RETAINED?

Comment: @DevOvercome set printer attribute PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_KEEPPRINTEDJOBS to get JOB_STATUS_PRINTED but don t froget to remove job in spooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you meant `JOB_STATUS_RETAINED` when you said RETAINED, I found this link [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145019(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Windows Vista and later: Job has been retained in the print queue and cannot be deleted. This can be caused by the following:
>   1) The job was manually retained by a call to SetJob and the spooler is waiting for the job to be released.
>   2) The job has not finished printing and must finish printing before it can be automatically deleted.
>   See SetJob for more information about print job commands.

From SetJob documentation:

> JOB_CONTROL_RETAIN
>   Windows Vista and later: Keep the job in the queue after it prints.
>   JOB_CONTROL_RELEASE
>   Windows Vista and later: Release the print job.

From the documentation, it seems that `SetJob(JOB_CONTROL_RELEASE)` could be used to release the job.